# Excel Drag to increment sheet name between file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

how to drag to increment the excel sheet from different file?

eg,

```
Cell A1 =+'[filename]59'!J6
Cell B1 =+'[filename]60'!J6
Cell C1 =+'[filename]61'!J6
```

i tried this now 
`=INDIRECT("SHEET"&COLUMN()-1&"!J6")`
and readjust all the name etc, and now i wanna drag down and increment the cell to J7,J8,J9 etc

how do i do it?

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Try `=INDIRECT("SHEET"&COLUMN()-1&"!J"&ROW())`.  ROW() returns your current row.  So, if you write `=ROW()` in A15, you'll get 15.  Good for dragging down :)

If you want to change the value so that it matches a row different from your current row, you'll need to add or subtract from ROW().  So, if you wanted to put this in some cell B2 or C2 and have it match up to J5, you'd have to add 3.  That would work like this:

`=INDIRECT("SHEET"&COLUMN()-1&"!J"&(ROW()+3))`

Obviously, you should change the `3` to whatever adjustment value you need.

Comment: I think this answer gets the job done, but you may want to explain what the `ROW()` formula does, and format this as a code block :)

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

just that i need to adjust the place it show the value, if you could explain what it does would be really great

i think i got it.

THANKS A MILLION TIMES!

Comment: Excellent.  Is there anything else you need?